# I don't find 'WebRole.cs' file in my PHP Web ROle

Tags: php, azure, azure-diagnostics

I am having problems while trying to configure Windows Azure Diagnostics in a PHP Web Role. I have read that I have to modificate the `OnStart()` method in the **WebRole.cs** file, right? But the problem is that I don't find this file in my project. I don't have it! I thought that this file was created automatically, or, do I have to create it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary to add any code to a WebRole.cs file (you won't have one in PHP).

However, you can set up diagnostics by adding the diagnostics module to your package. You can do this by modifying your ServiceDefinition.csdef (assuming you have one) to include the diagnostics module like this:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="xxx">
  <WebRole name="xxx" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

You then need to set the storage account that you want the diagnostics information written to, by modifying the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg to add a setting like this:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="xxx" osFamily="1" osVersion="*">
  <Role name="xxx">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting 
        name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" 
        value="YOUR_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

You then need to add a diagnostics.wadcfg file to your package, which tells the diagnostics module how you would like the information captured. There is an example of one here: https://gist.github.com/2520279

Comment: +1 for talking about adding diagnostics.wadcfg to your package. I thought it would only work if added to the container in the storage account, but including it in the package also works! More info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2011/03/29/configuring-wad-via-the-diagnostics-wadcfg-config-file.aspx

Comment: Ok. I get it! My problem was the configuration file, because I had to change the tag <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB> for <BufferQuotaInMB>1</BufferQuotaInMB>. Anyway now I need to set up the "Performance Counters". For doing this, do I need to change the OnStart method? Or can I do it with a configuration file? Thanks!!

Comment: The performance counters can be configured with the diagnostics.wadcfg file. The example I gave has some in.

Comment: Ah, great!! And the last doubt :) I think I'm having a problem with the diagnostics.wadcfg file. The problem is that I think that the Diagnostic Monitor isn't using our diagnostics.wadcfg file. In fact there isn't any wad-control-container file, and when the instance starts this file appears, and with a configuration different that the diagnostics.wadcfg. I think that the Diagnostic Monitor is using this new file instead. Thanks again!!